# Updating Bootstrap Datetimepicker for auto displaying end date calendar, when start date is selected

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap Datetimepicker in a form.
I want a functionality so when a user selects a date in start date column calendar it should automatically show the end date calendar

Here's the structure:

```
<div id="displaydate" >
   <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group dt_picker">
         <div class='input-group date date-margin' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class=" date_pick_bg hasDatepicker form-control date-picker input_date_wrap" placeholder="Start Date"  id="datetimepicker1ip" name="para4" value="<?php echo($datestring1); ?>"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon1">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group dt_picker">
         <div class='input-group date date-margin' id='datetimepicker2'>
            <input type='text' class="date_pick_bg hasDatepicker form-control date-picker input_date_wrap" placeholder="End Date" id="datetimepicker2ip" name="para5" value="<?php echo($datestring2); ?>"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon2">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

All I want to identify element class/id, on click of which I can trigger  click on "input-group-addon2".

Comment: can you add snippet or atleast cdn of bootstrap and datepicker?

Comment: Shouldn't you leave the class `hasDatepicker` out? Isn't that added by the `datepicker()` function only after the datepicker has been initialized?